# Grouping multiple lines in csv to one line and storing to variable

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

Most likely very simple but I am new to this and not really sure how to search for what I am trying to do. So far I have the file imported and sorted but I am not sure how to combine the multiple failures for the customer and store them. I just have them writing to host to make sure I was capturing the failures.

CSV Example

Result,SystemID,Customer
SUCCESS,123,CustomerA
FAIL,456,CustomerB
FAIL,456,CustomerB
FAIL,789,CustomerB
SUCCESS,111,CustomerC
FAIL,321,CustomerD

I need to store the failures to be emailed separately for each customer.
Email Customer B
System/s (456) & (789) have failed
Email Customer D
System/s (321) have failed

```
Write-Host "CSVs: $CSVs"
foreach ($CSV in $CSVs) {
    $data = Import-Csv $CSV | Sort-Object Customer
    foreach ($line in $data) {
        if ($line.Result -eq "fail") {
            Write-Host  " Action should be taken for $($line.customer)" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
            Write-Host "$($line.Result) on SystemID's $($line.SystemID)"
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7) and [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7) to group your data based on Customer failures.

```
foreach ($CSV in $CSVs) {
    $data = Import-Csv $CSV | Sort-Object Customer
    $FailGroups = $data | Where Result -eq 'FAIL' | Group-Object Customer
    foreach ($FailGroup in $FailGroups) {
        $FailedCustomer = $FailGroup.Name
        $FailedSystems = ($FailGroup.Group.SystemID | Foreach-Object { "($_)" }) -join ' & '
        $MailMessage = "Systems/s {0} have failed" -f $FailedSystems
        $FailedCustomer # Outputting customers with failures
        $MailMessage # Outputting failed systems in formatted message
        # Below is a Custom Object that can be exported to CSV or retrieved later
        # [pscustomobject]@{'Customer' = $FailedCustomer; 'Message' = $MailMessage}
    }
}
```

You can now use `$FailedCustomer` and `$MailMessage` to craft your email message at the end of the inner `foreach` iteration.

Since `Group-Object` returns a `GroupInfo` object, you will need to access its `Name` property for the property values used to determine the grouping. The `Group` property contains the CSV rows (objects) that are included in the grouping.

---

If you go the custom object route, you can store all of the outputs into a single variable as an array. You can then export the array into a CSV file or iterate through the array for your email tasks.

```
$output = foreach ($CSV in $CSVs) {
    $data = Import-Csv $CSV | Sort-Object Customer
    $FailGroups = $data | Where Result -eq 'FAIL' | Group-Object Customer
    foreach ($FailGroup in $FailGroups) {
        $FailedCustomer = $FailGroup.Name
        $FailedSystems = ($FailGroup.Group.SystemID | Foreach-Object { "($_)" }) -join ' & '
        $MailMessage = "Systems/s {0} have failed" -f $FailedSystems
        [pscustomobject]@{'Customer' = $FailedCustomer; 'Message' = $MailMessage}
    }
}
# Export to CSV
$output | Export-Csv -Path C:\Path\FailedCustomers.csv -NoType
# Email customers example
foreach ($customer in $output) {
    $MailParams = @{
        'SmtpServer' = 'smtp.domain.com'
        'Subject' = 'Failures'
        'To' = $customer.Customer
        'From' = you@domain.com
        'Body' = $customer.Message
    }
    Send-MailMessage @MailParams
}
```

Comment: Thank you @AdminOfThings this works great! I really appreciate it.